# Why does the build.gradle (Project) disappear when I clone the project from Github in Android Studio 3.4.1?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, github

I create a project, both `build.gradle` (Project) and `build.gradle` (Module) are listed in Android folder structure normally, look likes *Old Image 1*, then I sync the project to remote GitHub in Android Studio 3.4.1.

I clone the project from GitHub in another PC, I find that `build.gradle` (Project) disappear in Android folder structure in the another PC, look likes *New Image 1*, but I can find it in Project folder structure, look likes *New Image 2*. Why? BTW, the clone project can work well.

It seems that Github cause the problem, how can I fix it? Thanks!

**Old Image 1**

[image]

**New Image 1**

[image]

**New Image 2**

[image]

**To InsurgentPointerException:**

This is project level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.8'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Again to InsurgentPointerException:**

You can test it by clone from

https://github.com/mycwcgr/aa

You can download the project source code of Android Studio at

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ko8stedl135ohnt/MyTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: So to clarify both of the build.gradle files are there... right? (Hi again.)

Comment: paste your project level build.gradle file.

Comment: Thanks! I have pasted the code of  project level build.gradle

Comment: It looks fine! I wonder what happened, let me dig a little more

Comment: Try reproducing the problem. Make a new project, put it on Github and paste the link

Comment: Thanks! Please see my updated content

Comment: @Blasanka It's seen in the "Project View". So your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: You can see .gitignore at https://github.com/mycwcgr/aa/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: I don't add build.gradle to .gitignore by myself !

Comment: I don't see any issues here. I see all the gradle files in Android View > Gradle Scripts

Comment: Waaaiiit a sec... So in my above comment I used AS 3.6. Now I switch to 3.4.1 and yes, I don't see it either.

Comment: Thanks! Android Studio 3.4.1 cause the problems, and Android Studio 3.6 fix the bugs, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it *seems* like the Developers did that intentionally. IDK there probably used to be some setting for it but now I can't find it. This solution is a (rather lengthy) workaround.

1. Close the target project
2. Rename the root project folder
3. Open the renamed project (Optional)
4. See that there is `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` in the the Android View > Gradle Scripts (Optional)
5. Close back out of the project (Optional)
6. Do 1 -> 4 again but renaming back to the old project name.

Comment: Thanks! According to what InsurgentPointerException said, Android Studio 3.4.1 cause the problems, and Android Studio 3.6 fix the bugs, right?

Comment: Yes, @HelloCW .

Comment: @HelloCW If my answer works, please upvote/accept. (Why didn't you award the bounty during the grace period?)

Comment: Thanks! I hope to get a better way, you way is too complex. And more, are you sure it is a bug of Android Studio 3.4.1 and  Android Studio 3.4.2?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes, I'm sure this is a bug. This has been the only way to fix it for me.